# Create Trigger in Postgres asking for avg()

Tags: sql, postgresql, triggers

I'm trying to create a Trigger that adds the average of one column from table A into table B after each insert into table A.
Table A (id (integer), rating (integer)) 
Table B (id (serial), average (integer))

My Trigger is:

```
CREATE TRIGGER rat_trig 
  AFTER INSERT ON a 
  FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE upd_rat_func();
```

My Trigger Function looks like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION upd_rat_func() RETURNS TRIGGER as $rating_update$
BEGIN
INSERT INTO b VALUES (DEFAULT, AVG(rating) FROM a);
RETURN NEW;
END;
$rating_update$ language plpgsql;
```

Postgres tells me there is an error in my function somewhere near or at 'from', yet I cannot find a way to make it work (The Trigger is not yet created, as I cannot create the function). Any help (or also any advice of where I can find more about the structure of trigger functions as the postgres documentation has been less than helpful) are very welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `FROM` has to belong to a `SELECT` (or a `DELETE`).

To use a subquery, use the complete query and put it into parentheses:

```
INSERT INTO b VALUES (DEFAULT, (SELECT AVG(rating) FROM a));
```

But that trigger does not make much sense to me. You want a new row with a new average for each `INSERT`? What about the other rows in `b`?

Perhaps you are looking for a [materialized view](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-creatematerializedview.html).

Comment: Thank you, this works. And yes, this was just the part of the code that wasn't working, the trigger is a little different actually.

Answer (score 0):

Here is PostgreSQL doc:

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/plpgsql-trigger.html

try changing INSERT statement for smth like this:

```
INSERT INTO b (average) SELECT AVG(rating) FROM a;
```

make sure it works before adding it to trigger function